# Create a list of check box by using the records from MySQL datebase as values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have asked this question before but no one could find the solution, so I'm asking again with updated code to see if anyone else can help me.

As the title says I am trying to create check boxes in my site. However, the values will come from the mysql database. I can't figure out where I have gone wrong as my php code wont execute.

I have a database called "my computer", table named `campus` and it has the 2 columns `id` and `room`.

Below is the screenshot of my database and the output of the code in the web browser:

[image]

[image]

```
<?PHP

$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$databaseName = "my computer";

$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

?>

<html>  
<body>

<form name="aform">

Choose a room:

    <?php

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `campus`";
    $result = mysqli_query($sql);
    mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

    while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    ?>

    <input type="checkbox" name="car" value="<?php echo $line['room'];?>" />

    <?php   
    }
    ?>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of posting your question again, please edit it and include the updated details / information

Comment: hi...will do , sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I look at your code and think the php block after "Choose a room" can be improved like this:

```
<?php
  $s = '';
  $j = 0;
  if ($q = $dbCon->query("SELECT * FROM `campus`")) {
    while ($line = $q->fetch_assoc()) {
      $s.= '<input type="checkbox" name="car'.$j.'" value="'.$line['room'].'">';
    }
  }
  echo $s;
?>
```

The `$j` variable is to avoid having all the inputs with same name.

Comment: hi, thankyou your code worked!.. however how would i go about adding a name on the side, to each of the checkboxes. for example: i have 2 values in my table in database therefore 2 checkboxes were outputted however they don't have any name tags on the side to differentiate which value is which?

Comment: after you close the tag input, add the name coming from the database: { <input type="checkbox" ...>my_name }

Comment: hi, but that would make all the name of the checkboxes the same? i want to individually name them separate

Comment: of course, you have to take the name from the database, so try "$line['name']" instead of "my_name" (assuming that the column of the table in the database is called "name")

Comment: can i use the same column called "room" to take the name as well as create the checkboxes or do i have to create another one to name the checkboxes?

Comment: created a new column called "name" to store the name however the output doesn't show anything? this is the line in the code:                 $s.= '<input type="checkbox" name="car'.$j.'" value="'.$line['room'].'">"$line['name']"';

Comment: messed up the quotes! - $s.= '<input type="checkbox" name="car'.$j.'" value="'.$line['room'].'">'.$line['name'];

Comment: thankyou! it worked, you are amazing at this.